# Fail to retrieve Post data with Laravel

Tags: laravel, forms, post, request

I try to learn Laravel (v.9) from scratch but fail to do a simple basic task:

I just want to send "post_var" by POST request and display the var.

My form (blade template):

```html
<form action="/post_and_show" method="POST">
     @csrf
     @method('post')
  <input type="text" name="post_var">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

My Route (in web.php) with some dd() i tried to find the problem

```php
Route::post('/post_and_show', function (Request $request) {
    dd($request->method()); // returns GET ?? !!
    // chrome debugger network tab show clearly its a POST request...

    dd($request->all());  // returns empty Array

    dd($request->post_var); // returns null

    dd($request->getContent());  // returns string but i want param only
    // "_token=yBBYpQ303a1tSiGtQF6zFCF6p6S7qadVfHMk4W7Q&_method=post&post_var=12345"
});
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Tried several methods i found in the documentation but non worked so far.

**EDIT:** I removed "@method('post')"
Btw.: My initial version that did not work either had no "@method('post')". I added it later on in the hope it might help...

```html
<form action="/post_and_show" method="POST">
     @csrf

  <input type="text" name="post_var">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

**But have still the same problems:**

```php
Route::post('/post_and_show', function (Request $request) {
     dd($request->method()); // returns GET ?? !!  but chrome says its a post request
     dd($request->post_var); // returns null
     dd($request->get('post_var'));// returns null
     dd($request->getContent()); // returns complete body and header in one string
     dd($request->all());  // return empty Array
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

Googleing i found "createFromGlobals":

```php
use Illuminate\HTTP\Request; // just added this to show which class i use here...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::post('/post_and_show', function () {
     dd(Request::createFromGlobals()->get('post_var')); // returning expected value
});
```

This works for me, but i can't find this method in documentation. Sorry,  i am new to laravel and even php,  so this seems all completely crazy to me.. ;-)

**EDIT 3:**

If i use a simple Controller it works too...

Controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FormController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request->post_var); // returns expected value...
    }
}
```

Route:

```php
Route::post('post_and_show', [FormController::class, 'show']);
```

So only in case i use the $request immediatly in the callback it does not work as expected. ( Either by design or bug??)

Comment: This usually happens when there's a redirect intercepting the first request. However because you have `@method('post')` you are "tricking" laravel into calling a post route with a get request which will make it harder to diagnose what the problem is.

Comment: ah, ok, wasn't aware of that.
Nevertheless after removing @method('post') i still get "GET" when calling method().
And the main Question is: What is a standard way in Laravel to retrieve POST vars? Can't imagine that this is so hard...

Comment: just remove @method('post')

Comment: i did, as mentioned above, there is no difference...

Comment: I test your code it's work fine no problem just remove @ method('post') because laravel use this @method to add hidden _method to  be used as the http request but for GET AND POST tht's is regular with html because html understand that and that's the way of html to send data so to make the http request to understand what we sent laravel use @ method with  PUT, PATCH or DELETE.

Comment: sorry, but i have to say the for third time:

there is no "@method('post')" any more and i have the very same results.

Its a fresh laravel installation, i even do not have any custom models or anything else. and this is the second project where i observe the exact same thing.

So if this should work in general, what might be wrong with my version?

Comment: @devpix If it's a fresh Laravel install, you're probably gonna need to look at webserver config. Start by using your browser's network inspector to look at the HTTP requests being made. I'll bet there's a redirect of some kind happening.

Comment: Browser says "POST 200 OK"   there is only one single request.

echo $request->method(); shows "GET"
its standard artisan server